# MediaWiki: restricting access to view/edit

Tags: mediawiki

Can MediaWiki combine with a Windows domain server, so people logged in with a domain account can view/edit pages?

Or at least has an account control mechanism so reach the above requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to look more into the [LDAP Authentication Extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:LDAP_Authentication), assuming you are using Active Directory or another LDAP provider to manage your Windows Domain.

The current version of the extension (1.2a (2009-05-06) as of writing) has been tested on the following Windows configurations:

> **LDAP Directories**
>
> - Active Directory 2003
>
> **Configurations**
>
> - Windows 2003, MediaWiki 1.8.3, PHP 5.2.0, MySQL 5.0, IIS6, Microsoft Active Directory
> - Windows Server 2003 SP2, MediaWiki 1.14, PHP 5.2.8,MySQL 5.0.51a, Apache Server 2.2, Microsoft Acrive Directory