# Is there a way to restrict read access to pages in MediaWiki?

Tags: linux, mediawiki

I have a MediaWiki site which is available for public view, and I want to keep it that way, but I would like to make certain pages private -- and viewable only by me.  I know this kind of goes against the entire purpose of a wiki, but to heck with that.  I don't let anyone sign up as an editor of the wiki -- I'm actually using MediaWiki as a CMS, when you get right down to it.  **This MediaWiki site is hosted on a Linux server.**

Yes, I know about "protecting" a page from certain editors, but I want certain pages invisible or not viewable except by specific users.  **I need a MediaWiki-based solution -- whether in the markup, or in the underlying PHP.**

If this isn't possible in the markup or the PHP, then fine, that's the answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MediaWiki: restricting access to view/edit](http://superuser.com/questions/109800/mediawiki-restricting-access-to-view-edit)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I saw that question, but the answer to it relies upon the site being on a Windows server -- which is why I included the sentence "This MediaWiki site is hosted on a Linux server."  Unless you can tell me that Active Directory or LDAP is available on Linux?

Comment: It's still the sae question (to me anyway), as the marked question is not Windows-specific (LDAP exists for other OSs), and also says "Or at least has an account control mechanism so reach the above requirement." presumably asked for if/when an LDAP/AD solution isn't available. I'd suggest placing a bounty (and an accompanying comment) to garner other answers on the original. Regardless, takes more than just my vote to close it. :)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I have changed the question so that it is looking for a MediaWiki-specific answer.  Yes, I know it takes more than one vote to close -- I have close-vote privileges in other SE's -- but vote #2 has arrived!  It's about to be strangled at birth! :-)

Comment: [Relevant MediaWiki Manual](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Preventing_access#Restrict_viewing_of_certain_specific_pages).  Basically it says, MediaWiki is not intended to be a CMS.  Use the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the answer to the question is: there is no way to do this and MediaWiki wasn't designed for this.

Answer (score 0):

It's more complicated to configure, but [Tiki Wiki](https://info.tiki.org/) has a concept of users and groups and was designed to handle the use-case you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can white list some of you MediaWiki pages like this.

```
    $wgWhitelistRead =  array ( "Special:Userlogin", 
    "Special:CreateAccount" );
    $wgGroupPermissions['*']['read'] = true;
    $wgGroupPermissions['*']['view'] = true;
    $wgGroupPermissions['*']['edit'] = false;
```