# mediawiki how to display information on the login page on a otherwise private wiki

Tags: mediawiki, creative-commons

I have setup a private wiki with mediawiki and i'm using a Logo under the CC license so I have to cite the source and the license.

Since my wiki is private and requires a login I need to find a way to display information on the login page and/or about page.

**Question 1: Is there a way to display specific pages without being logged in?**

**Question 2: If not, is there a way to add a global footer that is visible without being logged in ?**

Additional info:

I suppose I want the opposite asked in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/849023/is-there-a-way-to-restrict-read-access-to-pages-in-mediawiki) question:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add this page to `$wgWhitelistRead` as shown in [manual](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Preventing_access#Restrict_viewing_of_all_pages).